# IOS , what is mean of this syntax?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I just saw a syntax like below, could someone tell me what it means?

```
#define TOTAL_HOLES 6
int lookup[TOTAL_HOLES];
```

Comment: it's define an array named `lookup` wich contains 6  `integer`

Comment: Which bit don't you understand? The define, the declaration, the syntax, the result?

Comment: ok thx all !! The Int Lead Me To A Wrong Direction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#define TOTAL_HOLES 6
```

It is a preprocessor macro.

```
int lookup[TOTAL_HOLES];
```

It is an array of int